# Many Partitions in Hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, partitioning

I have about 200,000 distinct values for the column "id" and I have used it as a partition key in one of the dynamically partitioned Hive table.

Now the partitions are created and when I try to query (I have used simple 
`Select *` query), it always returns following error:

```
FAILED: SemanticException org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
```

Can anyone tell me why?

Comment: Have you looked at `hive.exec.max.dynamic.partitions.pernode`? I think 200,000 is far too many partitions - I've never exceeded a few hundred before.

Comment: @BenWatson I have modified this property based on number of values. I am using hive metastore in spark and I need to decrease the processing time so I chose dynamic partition. is there any other way to decrease the query time?

Comment: Reduce the number of partitions - do you really need 200,000?

Comment: yes because I am going to use only select * from where id='?'

Comment: You don't need partitions for that. You can just have ID as a column.

Comment: yes but it is very slow becoz hive scans entire rows but in partitions its not the case

Comment: Hive has been designed for massive queries, not for key/value access.For that kind of requirement, use a key/value system like HBase - or even MySQL.

Comment: BTW your error message probably means that the MetaStore queries its **MySQL** back-end to get the list of partitions, and the SQL query times out.

Answer (score 2):

Make use of Indexing feature of Hive(newly introduced) on column 'id'. Partitioning is not a good idea when too many partitions are getting creating, it's increases the load on the name node to track each of the partition created.

Answer (score 0):

You could select * from dividing the id. For example;

```
select * from where id >0 and id < 50000
select * from where id >=50000 and id =< 100000
...
```

Because for each dynamic partition, hive allocates a memory portion. This style of querying would need less memory, however the whole process takes more time.

Answer (score 0):

200,000 is too many dynamic partitions for hive. Try reducing the number of partitions.